# Merge two curves into new one like rhino

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

Hi guys Im trying really hard to find the best way to model an egg chair, and I came across a tutorial from rhino: https://youtu.be/1-rQqb921w0?t=9m4s That given 2 curves it does the wizardry of bounding them together.

Does blender have a similar modifier, curve option that can perform the same?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Rhino is a NURBS based modeling application, Blender has very basic support for NURBS, with limited tools , it can't be modeled that way in Blender. Look into the Bsurfaces addon for similar workflow https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?225190-Bsurfaces-v1-5 or model it properly using traditional mesh subdivision.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos True, I'm just trying to see if anybody as a trick that I'm missing to see... If there's none I will continue with the mesh subdivision ;) (4h into it right now...)

Comment: Look into the linked addon, or consider trying third party software, if that is an option. [MoI 3D](http://moi3d.com/) is a great and simple NURBS based 3D modeling tool. It is commercial but relatively cheap for its kind

Comment: do you mean using a curve that represents the top view and a curve that represents the side view and combine them (so similar to the boolean intersect)?

Comment: @FacebFaceb , I don't really understand how intersect would merge the two views like in the video. But the main concept, answered by Duarte, is yeah have to lines, or beziers and make a different path between the two. 
Thought i already model the chair (good old mesh subdivision) my question remains if someone know a try of doing that in the video above.

Comment: So if i understand correctly, you want two curves to connect like branches of a tree?

Comment: I tried to do it as a mesh and then converted to curve, but then they are separated again

Comment: @FacebFaceb, no I want something like Bsurfaces does. Tree branches are added right? you connect one to another. What I'm asking is if giving two curves blender could generate a Third completely different using the shapes of the two parent curves. Not connected at all, something different, like the video i linked.

Comment: first - in video it is fake armchair shape. not even near to original example.
second - in Sverchok we can make interpolation node mk# to deal. if you admit, he made row of curves along outer line, we can use only them and acheave the same result.
especially me will use for kind of stuff math for definition shape (real egg shape)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in sverchok, i use pink curve's z position and blue curve's xy position to create a new green curve.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the video the shape of the armchair is not close to the original example, which is OK if all it intends to do is show a technique.

In Sverchok we can use *interpolation node mk#* to interpolate the points of multiple curves, by sampling them along their trajectory. If you observe closely the videos, he made a row of curves along the exterior profile, those are all we need to achieve the same result. The outer curve profile (egg shape), can be generated via the math nodes.

[image]

In sverchok we can do the above and it all stays parametric, or use Blenders bundled "looptools" add-on at the cost of parametric interaction.